# Where Heroku stored the latest.dump file, when I import db from Heroku to local Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, dump, heroku-cli

This is how I import db from Heroku Postgres to local Postgres db:

1. Back up your database from Heroku

```
heroku pg:backups:capture -a your-app-name
```

2. Download the database from Heroku. The database will be downloaded as a latest.dump file to your computer

```
heroku pg:backups:download -a your-app-name
```

3. Import latest.dump to Postgres (your local database) (if this is the first dump, you don't need to specify the number of dump)

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U your_local_db_username -d your_local_db_name latest.dump.[number of dump]
```

I want to know where Heroku stored the latest.dump file from step number 2 in my computer. In which folder? Heroku silent about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it just puts it wherever you are on the filesystem when you run the command. If you didn't use the `-a` / `--app` argument, that's probably your project directory since Heroku would have to infer your app from your Git remotes.

[You can use](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-backups-download-backup_id) the `-o` / `--output` argument to put it elsewhere or give it a different name:

```
-o, --output=output  location to download to. Defaults to latest.dump
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! Please, give me one more answer for one more question: how can I delete dumps from Heroku? As far as I understand they are created on Heroku and then I can download them to my pc from there by: `heroku pg:backups:download -a your-app-name`. I want to delete this dumps also from Heroku sometimes

Comment: @TomasAngelo, there is [a `heroku pg:backups:delete` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-backups-delete-backup_id).

Comment: Sorry for asking you this question because I already dug into the Heroku CLI myself and found this command. But it doesn't have an option to delete all dumps. Therefore, I had another question, probably the last one: Will Heroku automatically delete database backups after a certain time? Because I, reading the documentation, do not quite understand - it will be deleted or not